# How to deal: zeros disappear

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt

I have a program and one of its tasks is to save data to DB (i'm using SQLite). Here is my writing to DB code:

```
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO " + DB_TABLE_OMEGA + "(KART, |. . . other stuff|) "             
                                              "VALUES(:KART, |. . . other stuff|)");
qry.bindValue(":KART", KART);                                                                        
|. . . other stuff|                                                                    
                                                                                                         
if(!qry.exec())                                                                                          
{                                                                                                        
    handleError("=(");                                                 
    exit(ERROR_CODE);                                                                                    
}
```

KART is a number with fixed size, saved as string. I get it by parsing xml file. Usually i have something like this "001036404". The string feels good during debugging so the problem lies in the process of writing to the DB.

The database table column is simple:

```
KART STRING
```

**The problem:**

After pushing data to db, SQLite saves my number without leading zeros like this:

> "001036404" is pushed  --->  "1036404" is saved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `STRING` data type in SQLite as it is explained in [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

If you define the data type of a column as `STRING`, the column's [affinity will be determined](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) as `NUMERIC` and as such any numeric value with leading `0`s or trailing `0`s after the decimal point will be stored without them.

Redefine the column's data type as `TEXT`.